# Python: How does one get root access for a GUI session (linux)

Tags: python, linux, root, sudo, privileges

I'm trying to write a GUI that requires root for some operations (it modifies and accesses system files at different stages in the process (see [gui.py](https://gitlab.com/NamingThingsIsHard/linux/plymouth-bootscreen-creator/-/blob/master/pbc/gui.py)). Right now, when multiple operations are executed using `pkexec`, `kdesudo` or `gksudo`, however those don't grant "session" root access, meaning every time root access is needed, a new popup is required, asking the user to enter the root password.

Is there a way to get root access for that program for a session? I know that in the terminal, using `sudo`, access is granted for a specific amount of time (how long I don't know), but don't know the mechanics behind that, nor how to replicate it in a GUI.

**I do not want the entire GUI to run in root**. I know of the [`elevate`](https://pypi.org/project/elevate/) package, but it makes debugging hard as it's not easy to step through code anymore. Additionally, the virtual env doesn't seem to work (env vars are cleaned?).

My intuition would be to create a child, root process that waits for stdin from the parent and executes the commands passed to it from there. The commands could pass through an `argparse.ArgumentParser` e.g

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="command")
# Add subparsers and their arguments
while True:
  input_line = input()
  try:
    args = parser.parse_args(shlex(input_line))
    if args.command == "some_command":
      some_command(*args)
    elif args.command == "other_command":
      other_command(*args)
  except Exception as exception:
    handle_exception(exception)
    # TODO handle exit?
```

but I don't know how secure that is. The child process wouldn't be able to execute any commands besides the one it knows, but still...

Comment: One reasonably sane approach would be to add all the commands you know you'll need to run to a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` with a `NOPASSWD` option.  The reason that you keep getting prompted is that you're indeed spawning a new shell for each command, and the time-out isn't per user but per process by default. You could also modify `tty_tickets` and `timestamp_timeout` ...

Comment: I had a look at `/etc/sudoers.d/` and it might cause an issue with `pip install --user` installations. `kdesu` seems to create a new session each time it's called, even when done in a terminal.

Comment: What about option two? Feasible?

Comment: Those require modifying system files and I would like this to work on a self-contained solution, that doesn't have unexpected side effects for the user - modifying system configuration to be functional would be an important side effect. It might not be possible without those side-effect though 